# Getting error while using quill editor in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, quill

I am working on a Flutter project, my Dart and Flutter SDK is Flutter: Flutter 3.3.10
Dart: Dart 2.18.6, I am using quill version: 6.4.2
but while running the app I am getting these errors:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_quill-6.4.2/lib/src/widgets/raw_editor.dart:308:8: Error: Type 'ContextMenuButtonItem' not found.
  List<ContextMenuButtonItem> get contextMenuButtonItems {
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_quill-6.4.2/lib/src/widgets/raw_editor.dart:327:3: Error: Type 'TextSelectionToolbarAnchors' not found.
  TextSelectionToolbarAnchors get contextMenuAnchors {
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_quill-6.4.2/lib/src/widgets/raw_editor.dart:1516:7: Error: Type 'TextInputControl' not found.
      TextInputControl? oldControl, TextInputControl? newControl) {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_quill-6.4.2/lib/src/widgets/raw_editor.dart:1516:37: Error: Type 'TextInputControl' not found.
      TextInputControl? oldControl, TextInputControl? newControl) {
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_quill-6.4.2/lib/src/widgets/raw_editor.dart:125:12: Error: Undefined name 'AdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar'.
    return AdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar.buttonItems(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_quill-6.4.2/lib/src/widgets/raw_editor.dart:309:25: Error: Member not found: 'EditableText.getEditableButtonItems'.        
    return EditableText.getEditableButtonItems(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_quill-6.4.2/lib/src/widgets/raw_editor.dart:331:12: Error: The getter 'TextSelectionToolbarAnchors' isn't defined for the  
class 'RawEditorState'.
 - 'RawEditorState' is from 'package:flutter_quill/src/widgets/raw_editor.dart'
 ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_quill-6.4.2/lib/src/widgets/raw_editor.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'TextSelectionToolbarAnchors'.
    return TextSelectionToolbarAnchors.fromSelection(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_quill-6.4.2/lib/src/widgets/raw_editor.dart:1516:7: Error: 'TextInputControl' isn't a type.
      TextInputControl? oldControl, TextInputControl? newControl) {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_quill-6.4.2/lib/src/widgets/raw_editor.dart:1516:37: Error: 'TextInputControl' isn't a type.
      TextInputControl? oldControl, TextInputControl? newControl) {
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_quill-6.4.2/lib/src/widgets/raw_editor.dart:1522:20: Error: The method 'intentForMacOSSelector' isn't defined for the class
'RawEditorState'.
 - 'RawEditorState' is from 'package:flutter_quill/src/widgets/raw_editor.dart'
 ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_quill-6.4.2/lib/src/widgets/raw_editor.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'intentForMacOSSelector'.
    final intent = intentForMacOSSelector(selectorName);
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_quill-6.4.2/lib/src/widgets/raw_editor.dart:1527:17: Error: Inferred type argument 'dynamic' doesn't conform to the bound
'Intent' of the type variable 'T' on 'Actions.invoke'.
 - 'Intent' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/actions.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/actions.dart').
 - 'Actions' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/actions.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/actions.dart').
Try specifying type arguments explicitly so that they conform to the bounds.
        Actions.invoke(primaryContext, intent);
                ^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/actions.dart:860:25: Context: This is the type variable whose bound isn't conformed to.
  static Object? invoke<T extends Intent>(
                        ^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_quill-6.4.2/lib/src/widgets/text_selection.dart:228:10: Error: Method 'insert' cannot be called on 'OverlayState?' because 
it is potentially null.
 - 'OverlayState' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/overlay.dart').
Try calling using ?. instead.
        .insert(toolbar!);
         ^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_quill-6.4.2/lib/src/widgets/text_selection.dart:354:10: Error: Method 'insertAll' cannot be called on 'OverlayState?'      
because it is potentially null.
 - 'OverlayState' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/overlay.dart').
Try calling using ?. instead.
        .insertAll(_handles!);
         ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_quill-6.4.2/lib/src/widgets/toolbar/quill_font_family_button.dart:112:41: Error: Property 'context' cannot be accessed on  
'OverlayState?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'OverlayState' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/overlay.dart').
Try accessing using ?. instead.
    final overlay = Overlay.of(context).context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
                                        ^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_quill-6.4.2/lib/src/widgets/toolbar/quill_font_size_button.dart:113:41: Error: Property 'context' cannot be accessed on    
'OverlayState?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'OverlayState' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/overlay.dart').
Try accessing using ?. instead.
    final overlay = Overlay.of(context).context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
           

                         ^^^^^^^
```

I have tried installing multiple versions of quill but it's showing the same issue.

Comment: Hi, if you still facing this issue please consider reporting it in GitHub repository for the `flutter_quill`

Answer (score 0):

am having the same error. According to an answer on Github, the flutter quill don't support flutter beta channel but stable. So if you're on beta, you'd have to switch to stable

flutter channel stable